# JavaScript NPM Package for escaping xml to handle special characters but leave the xml tags alone

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, npm, unicode-escapes

Does anyone know of a javascript npm package which will escape the values in an xml document but leave the xml tags alone? It would be great if we could just include the letters a through z both upper and lower case and the digits 0 through 9 and spaces in the values. Thanks, Greg

Comment: What kind of escaping do you want to apply? Can you provide examples of input and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably accomplish this using JavaScript's RegEx functions. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried two npm package xml-escape and xml-sanitizer and tried using the replace function.  Thanks